# Range appliance outlet circuit breaker

Tags: range

The appliance outlet circuit breaker atop the range back blew some time ago when a hand mixer that was plugged into it died in a 'flash'. I have been unable to reset the little breaker associated with it, and therefore cannot use the outlet. Suggestions appreciated. Whirlpool glasstop range about 2-3 years old.

Comment: 1 - Is this receptacle **part of** the Whirlpool range? Or a receptacle mounted in the wall above it?
2 - "little breaker associated with it" - Is that a GFCI built-in to the receptacle? Or something else?
3 - Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: Picture help a lot to help you

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.